# Camel 3.x upgrade

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm upgrading to camel 3.x and having some trouble finding methods. Their [migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html) doesn't quite cover everything. Specifically, I'm looking for the replacement to:

```java
camelContext.addRouteDefinitions(...)
...
camelContext.getRouteDefinitions()
```

I haven't been able to find anything in the docs for either of these.

Edit:

I can call them directly using this:

```java
camelContext.getExtension(Model.class).getRouteDefinitions()
```

But that doesn't seem right to do...

Comment: Its does not look wrong either. A lot has changed on the core of Camel to be compatible with Java 11. Try asking on the github for camel. They might have an answer. I am still getting up to speed with it,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do

```
ModelCamelContext mcc = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class);
```

Where you can access the model related APIs from CamelContext.